# Use proxy for stock android download manager? Play store not downloading through shadowsocks

Tags: google-play-store, downloading, vpn, proxy, download-manager

I'm in China.
I use proxy to access GFW blocked sites.
Proxy is connected as an android VPN.
Stock download manager does not go through proxy.
How can I use proxy with it?

On my Mi Mix 2S, I just opened the download manager app and disabled "Xunlei Download Acceleration" and then it worked. But there is no download manager app to open on my Nexus, and I can't find any settings related to it.

Now on my Nexus, everything I download in google play store is stuck at "Downloading...", without even starting the download process.

How can I configure the download manager so that it uses the proxy?

```
More Info:
•   Proxy App: Shadowsocks 4.8.0

•   Android Version: 9
•   StatiX OS Version: v2.0-OFFICIAL-20190225-2252
•   Android Security Patch Level: February 5, 2019
•   Kernel Version: 
    o   3.10.108-Statix-Pie-g950b2df
    o   #1 Mon Feb 25 22:58:17 UTC 2019
•   Build Number: PQ2A.190205.003 release-keys
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to force everything through a server like a proxy on Android is a vpn. There are several apps to use a proxy via vpn

The theory is that if you get a bad proxy not everything is effected. Generally only web browsers respect proxy configuration and other apps must specifically support it (which they do not generally)

Also check the proxy configuration and that it is accessible